# A way access field content with liquid

Tags: orchardcms

I am using the latest NuGet version of orchard core. As I want to use Bulma as CSS Framework, I Need to create tepmlates. One of several Problems that I have is: How can I Access the field contents from within a liquid template.

For instance the Blog theme has the content type Article. Within Article there is a field *Subtitle*. I created the template *Article-TextField* as

```html
<h2 class="subtitle">{{ Model.Field.Text }}</h2>
```

The similar .cshtml template works, but apparently with a liquid template, there is no way to Access the TextField *Text* property. How can I do it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the OrchardCore.ContentFields module doesn't register the `TextField` type with the Liquid's `TemplateContext.GlobalMemberAccessStrategy` service, which prevents you from accessing any members on the `TextField` object.

The module does register `DisplayTextFieldViewModel` like so:

```csharp
TemplateContext.GlobalMemberAccessStrategy.Register<DisplayTextFieldViewModel>();
```

Not only is this unnecessary because the `LiquidViewTemplate` already registers the model automatically, it also doesn't help you much, since you can only access the model's `Field` property, but not its `Text` property.

For example, this will yield some output:

`{{ Model }}`

This will too:

`{{ Model.Field }}`

But as you correctly noticed, this won't:

`{{ Model.Field.Text }}`

This is clearly an omission in Orchard Core, specifically in the ContentFields module.

Since you're using the NuGet packages, you can't hack it into the source code obviously. But what you could do is add a `Startup` class to your theme that derives from `StartupBase` and add the following static constructor:

```
static Startup()
{
    TemplateContext.GlobalMemberAccessStrategy.Register<TextField>();
}
```

Make sure to reference the OrchardCore.ContentFields NuGet package and import the `OrchardCore.ContentFields.Fields` namespace for your theme to compile.

After that, you will be able to access the `Text` property from your Liquid template.

Finally, I would recommend that you file an issue on GitHub about this omission so that you can ultimately remove the code I mentioned from your theme's Startup file.